# Cannot find Microsoft.Office.Interop in Visual Studio 2017 express edition

Tags: c#, wpf

While developing a software in visual studio 2017 all microsoft related references are not working. i am trying to add references through **Right_click on references -> Assemblies**. but no office related references are not found there.

Later i tried with nuget package manage controller to install required office packages that is also not working. I am getting the following errors, Please help me out.[Errors list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92sVv.png)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need to add the *COM reference* to the Office product that you want to work with, which then causes Visual Studio to automatically add the matching Office interop assembly. But it's been a while since I last needed this, so I'm not sure.

Comment: How to add COM reference to office product

Comment: The Add Reference window has a "COM" tab.

Comment: There i am not able to find any references related to Microsoft office

Comment: Which version of Office do you have installed on your PC?

Comment: Microsoft Office 365 Business

Comment: Should be there. Which Office application (Word, Excel, ...) do you want to automate?

Comment: Excel and outlook

Comment: Do you see an entry starting with "Microsoft Excel" in the Add References/COM list?

Comment: no i am not able to find. any how i had solved that issue by adding the packages through nuget package manager.
Now i am facing other problem that is if i try to build the solution it is showing 0 errors and build is failed

Comment: It should be there. If it isn't, something might be wrong with your Office installation. Maybe try repairing it.

Comment: I had repaired it.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. It might be worth starting a new question on why the Office COM references don't show up even though Office is installed.